# Convert a tensor to numpy array in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

How to convert a tensor into a numpy array when using Tensorflow with Python bindings?

Answer (score 239, accepted):

## **TensorFlow 2.x**

[Eager Execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager) is enabled by default, so just call [**`.numpy()`**](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L1042-L1067) on the Tensor object.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([[1, 2], [3, 4]])                 
b = tf.add(a, 1)

a.numpy()
# array([[1, 2],
#        [3, 4]], dtype=int32)

b.numpy()
# array([[2, 3],
#        [4, 5]], dtype=int32)

tf.multiply(a, b).numpy()
# array([[ 2,  6],
#        [12, 20]], dtype=int32)
```

See [NumPy Compatibility](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/basics) for more. It is worth noting (from the docs),

> Numpy array may share a memory with the Tensor object. **Any changes to one may be reflected in the other.**

Bold emphasis mine. A copy may or may not be returned, and this is an implementation detail based on whether the data is in CPU or GPU (in the latter case, a copy has to be made from GPU to host memory).

**But why am I getting the `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`?**.
A lot of folks have commented about this issue, there are a couple of possible reasons:

- TF 2.0 is not correctly installed (in which case, try re-installing), or
- TF 2.0 is installed, but eager execution is disabled for some reason. In such cases, call [`tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/enable_eager_execution) to enable it, or see below.

---

If Eager Execution is disabled, you can build a graph and then run it through `tf.compat.v1.Session`:

```
a = tf.constant([[1, 2], [3, 4]])                 
b = tf.add(a, 1)
out = tf.multiply(a, b)

out.eval(session=tf.compat.v1.Session())    
# array([[ 2,  6],
#        [12, 20]], dtype=int32)
```

See also [TF 2.0 Symbols Map](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FLFJLzg7WNP6JHODX5q8BDgptKafq_slHpnHVbJIteQ/edit#gid=0) for a mapping of the old API to the new one.

Comment: How to do this INSIDE a tf.function?

Comment: @mentalmushroom Couldn't find a documentation but it is mentioned in the  [customizations manual](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/basics#numpy_compatibility). More details can be found in the [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L918).

Comment: I get the following error in TF 2.0:
"'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'"

Comment: @Will.Evo it's possible you disabled eager execution before running this. Check the second half of my answer where you can use `eval()`.

Comment: No I did not disable eager execution. Still get AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot reproduce your problem, this answer still continues to work for me just fine. If anyone else facing this problem could provide more information I'd be happy to look into it.

Comment: why do I get an AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Comment: @zheyuanWang Are you still facing this issue? What if you call `tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution() ` in advance?

Comment: I didn't try that but run the script in Tensorflow 2.x environment instead. Everything works well there.

Comment: The tensor I was using had a gradient in addition to its value. I used `mytensor.detach().numpy()`.

Comment: I had the same issue in a tf.function(): combining numpy and tensorflow results in the original error and the solution .nump() does also not work in my gpu environment. But what has worked for me is the other way around: I transformed the numpy array into a tensorflow tensor via  `tf.convert_to_tensor` [Doku](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor)

Comment: I use Tensorflow 2.x, eager execution is enabled and still my tensor is a Tensor and not an EagerTensor and .numpy() does not work.

Answer (score 147):

Any tensor returned by `Session.run` or `eval` is a NumPy array.

```
>>> print(type(tf.Session().run(tf.constant([1,2,3]))))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Or:

```
>>> sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
>>> print(type(tf.constant([1,2,3]).eval()))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Or, equivalently:

```
>>> sess = tf.Session()
>>> with sess.as_default():
>>>    print(type(tf.constant([1,2,3]).eval()))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

**EDIT:** Not *any* tensor returned by `Session.run` or `eval()` is a NumPy array. Sparse Tensors for example are returned as SparseTensorValue:

```
>>> print(type(tf.Session().run(tf.SparseTensor([[0, 0]],[1],[1,2]))))
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensorValue'>
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'

Comment: If eval alone suffices, what is the reason for having Session.run or InteractiveSession in all of these options?

Comment: @Ceph If you run without a session, you get the following error:  `ValueError: Cannot evaluate tensor using 'eval()': No default session is registered. Use 'with sess.as_default()' or pass an explicit session to 'eval(session=sess)'`

Answer (score 83):

To convert back from tensor to numpy array you can simply run `.eval()` on the transformed tensor.

Comment: to clarify: yourtensor.eval()

Comment: I get `ValueError: Cannot evaluate tensor using 'eval()': No default session is registered. Use 'with sess.as_default()' or pass an explicit session to 'eval(session=sess)'`
Is this usable only during a tensoflow session?

Comment: @EduardoPignatelli It works for me in Theano with no extra work. Not sure about tf.

Comment: @EduardoPignatelli you need to run the `.eval()` method call from inside a session:  `sess = tf.Session();  with sess.as_default(): print(my_tensor.eval())`

Comment: By using this I am getting error as  
    AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'eval'

Comment: I have the same issue!

Answer (score 19):

## **Regarding Tensorflow 2.x**

The following generally works, since eager execution is activated by default:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([[1, 2], [3, 4]])                 
b = tf.add(a, 1)

print(a.numpy())
# [[1 2]
#  [3 4]]
```

However, since a lot of people seem to be posting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

I think it is fair to mention that calling `tensor.numpy()` in graph mode will ***not*** work. That is why you are seeing this error. Here is a simple example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def add():
  a = tf.constant([[1, 2], [3, 4]])                 
  b = tf.add(a, 1)
  tf.print(a.numpy()) # throws an error!
  return a
add()
```

A simple explanation can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38887#issuecomment-623104100):

> Fundamentally, one cannot convert a graph tensor to numpy array because the graph does not execute in Python - so there is no NumPy at graph execution. [...]

It is also worth taking a look at the TF [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_graphs).

## **Regarding Keras models with Tensorflow 2.x**

This also applies to `Keras` models, which are wrapped in a `tf.function` by default. If you really need to run `tensor.numpy()`, you can set the parameter `run_eagerly=True` in `model.compile(*)`, but this will influence the performance of your model.

Answer (score 9):

You need to:

1. encode the image tensor in some format (jpeg, png) to binary tensor
2. evaluate (run) the binary tensor in a session
3. turn the binary to stream
4. feed to PIL image
5. (optional) displaythe image with matplotlib

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PIL

...

image_tensor = <your decoded image tensor>
jpeg_bin_tensor = tf.image.encode_jpeg(image_tensor)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # display encoded back to image data
    jpeg_bin = sess.run(jpeg_bin_tensor)
    jpeg_str = StringIO.StringIO(jpeg_bin)
    jpeg_image = PIL.Image.open(jpeg_str)
    plt.imshow(jpeg_image)
```

This worked for me. You can try it in a ipython notebook. Just don't forget to add the following line:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you can try，this method:

```
import tensorflow as tf
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -1.0, 1.0))
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
array = W1.eval(sess)
print (array)
```

Answer (score 4):

I have faced and solved the *tensor->ndarray* conversion in the specific case of tensors representing (adversarial) images, obtained with *cleverhans* library/tutorials.

I think that my question/answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443777/how-to-convert-tensor-to-ndarray-tensor-with-adversarial-images-inside/52445055#52445055)) may be an helpful example also for other cases.

I'm new with TensorFlow, mine is an empirical conclusion:

It seems that tensor.eval() method may need, in order to succeed, also the value for input *placeholders*. 
Tensor may work like a function that needs its input values (provided into `feed_dict`) in order to return an output value, e.g.

```
array_out = tensor.eval(session=sess, feed_dict={x: x_input})
```

Please note that the placeholder name is **x** in my case, but I suppose you should find out the right name for the input *placeholder*. 
`x_input` is a scalar value or array containing input data.

In my case also providing `sess` was mandatory.

My example also covers the *matplotlib* image visualization part, but this is OT.

Answer (score 4):

I was searching for days for this command.

This worked for me outside any session or somthing like this.

```
# you get an array = your tensor.eval(session=tf.compat.v1.Session())
an_array = a_tensor.eval(session=tf.compat.v1.Session())
```

https://kite.com/python/answers/how-to-convert-a-tensorflow-tensor-to-a-numpy-array-in-python

Answer (score 3):

You can use keras backend function.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend 

sess = backend.get_session()
array = sess.run(< Tensor >)

print(type(array))

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

A simple example could be,

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    import numpy as np
    a=tf.random_normal([2,3],0.0,1.0,dtype=tf.float32)  #sampling from a std normal
    print(type(a))
    #<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
    tf.InteractiveSession()  # run an interactive session in Tf.
```

n
now if we want this tensor a to be converted into a numpy array

```
    a_np=a.eval()
    print(type(a_np))
    #<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

As simple as that!

Comment: `//` is not for commenting in python. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you see there is a method **_numpy()**,
e.g for an EagerTensor simply call the above method and you will get an ndarray.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to transform a TensorGPU into an np.array using the following :

```
np.array(tensor_gpu.as_cpu())
```

(using the TensorGPU directly would only lead to a single-element array containing the TensorGPU).

Answer (score 0):

## TensorFlow 1.x

Folder `tf.1`, just use the following commands:

```
a = tf.constant([[1, 2], [3, 4]])                 
b = tf.add(a, 1)
out = tf.multiply(a, b)
out.eval(session=tf.Session())
```

And the output would be:

```
# array([[ 2,  6],
#       [12, 20]], dtype=int32)
```