# TensorFlow tensor to Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, tensorflow

My model learns W:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([pixels,h1],stddev=np.sqrt(2.0 / (pixels))))
```

I return W from a function that runs my TF graph / session.

In my notebook, I checked type of W:

```
type(W)
out: tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable
```

I also checked dimensionality of W:

```
W.get_shape()
out: TensorShape([Dimension(3072), Dimension(1024)])
```

I'd like to convert W into a Pandas dataframe (for examination, etc.).

How can I do this?

(Saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097281/how-can-i-convert-a-tensor-into-a-numpy-array-in-tensorflow) on converting tensor to numpy with `eval()`, which could then be written to pandas of course. But that operation only seemed to work within the TF session.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

variables only exist within a session.  they are defined in the graph, as operations, but dont actually store any values as such, in the graph . they only have values when a session is created from the graph, and initialize operation called (or load is called).

Of course, once you've loaded the value from the varaible, in a session, using `eval`, you're free to dispose of the session, and use the resulting numpy tensor jsut as any normal numpy tensor.

Comment: right, got it. as you said, i re-wrote W as numpy tensor (W = W.eval()) within the session and returned from function call / fed into pandas.