# Can you save a Tensorflow variable as a string, or to a stream?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm farmilliar with [tf.train.Saver](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver), which allows me to save variables to disk.

But is it possible to get them directly as a string? Or write them to an open stream? Something like:

```
binary_string_rep = saver.save(sess)
db.save(binary_string_rep)
```

Or do I have to write to disk, then read it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert any tensor to Numpy array. Then use Numpy array as you wish! for example your model has `W_layer1` as weights for first layer. You can convert it to Numpy like : `W_numpy = W_layer1.eval()` which is mentioned also here: [Tensor to Numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097281/how-can-i-convert-a-tensor-into-a-numpy-array-in-tensorflow)

Comment: Good idea! Thanks