# Is it possible to transform an 1D tensor to a list ? (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is it possible to transform a 1D tensor to a list ?

thank you

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097281/how-can-i-convert-a-tensor-into-a-numpy-array-in-tensorflow - it is relatively straightforward to convert to an array, from which you can use `list()` to convert to a list

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't see this question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a tensor into a numpy array in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097281/how-can-i-convert-a-tensor-into-a-numpy-array-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 18):

```
l = tf.Variable([0, 1, 2, 3]).numpy().tolist()
type(l)
>>> list

l
>>> [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

This  method lets convert to list not only 1D tensor, but  also any other shape

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
a = tf.make_tensor_proto(a)
a = tf.make_ndarray(a)
a = a.tolist()
```

OR

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
a = a.numpy().tolist()
```