# How to convert Keras Tensor into numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm struggling to convert a simple Keras tensor into a Numpy array. This is the code I want to perform:

```
input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(100, 1), name='input')
inputs = np.array(input)
```

Error: `Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array.`

Comment: What is your numpy version? try using numpy version less than 1.20, pip install numpy==1.19.5

Comment: Why do you need to do this? I feel this is an XY problem.

Comment: I used numpy 1.19.5, here is a link to a colab : https://colab.research.google.com/gist/minh28/35597cc566b4797949142c7bcc5eedb2/50155.ipynb

Comment: Need to use this because I need to re use a code written from a previous version of Keras and Tensorflow. However I need to use a more recent version of those librairies now but with the same code.

Comment: Keras Tensor can not be converted to Numpy array directly, Convert Keras tensor to Tensor and from Tensor to numpy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First things first. Your `input` is not a tensor, but a symbolic tensor.

1. So, what is symbolic tensor? - You can consider it as tensor without any value associated with it.
2. Now, what is the use of symbolic tensor? - it actually helps you build a model framework so that it is ready to accept the input anytime later.

More can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59707558)

Now, coming back to answer your question. You need to convert the symbolic tensor to a tensor by first feeding the network with the data. Once you have the tensor, then you can proceed to get the numpy array out of it.