# How do I compute one hot encoding using tf.one_hot?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to build a one hot encoding of y_train of **mnist** data-set using **tensorflow**. I couldn't understand how to do it?

```
# unique values 0 - 9
y_train = array([5, 0, 4, ..., 5, 6, 8], dtype=uint8)
```

In `keras` we'll do something like

```
# this converts it into one hot encoding
one hot_encoding = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train)
```

Where as in `tf.one_hot` what should be my input to `indices` & `depth` parameters? After doing one hot encoding how can I convert it back to **numpy** array from **2d-tensor**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Tensorflow but after some tests, this is what I've found:

`tf.one_hot()` takes an `indices` and a `depth`. The `indices` are the values to actually convert to a one-hot encoding. `depth` refers to the maximum value to utilize.

For example, take the following code:

```
y = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y)
sess = tf.Session();
with sess.as_default():
    print(tf.one_hot(y, 2).eval())
    print(tf.one_hot(y, 4).eval())
    print(tf.one_hot(y, 6).eval())
```

`tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y)` Returns the following:

```
array([[0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

In contrast, the `tf.one_hot()` options (2, 4, and 6) do the following:

```
[[0. 1.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]
 [0. 1.]]
[[0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0.]]
[[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

As can be seen here, to mimic `tf.keras.utils.to_categorical()` using `tf.one_hot()`, the `depth` parameter should be equivalent to the maximum value present in the array, +1 for 0. In this case, the maximum value is 3, so there are four possible values in the encoding - 0, 1, 2, and 3. As such, a depth of 4 is required to represent all of these values in the one-hot encoding.

As for conversion to numpy, as shown above, using a Tensorflow session, running `eval()` on a tensor converts it to a numpy array. For methods on doing this, refer to [How can I convert a tensor into a numpy array in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097281).

I'm not familiar with Tensorflow but I hope this helps.

Note: for the purposes of MNIST, a depth of 10 should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to counter what @Andrew Fan has said. First, the above y label list does not start at index 0, which is what is required. Just look at the first column (i.e. index 0) in all of those examples: they're all empty. This will create a redundant class in the learning and may cause problems. One hot creates a simple list with 1 for that index position and zeros elsewhere. Therefore, your depth has to be the same as the number of classes, but you also have to start at index 0.