# error in converting tensor to numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I'm trying to convert input_image which is a tensor to numpy array.Following the already answered questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097281/how-can-i-convert-a-tensor-into-a-numpy-array-in-tensorflow) and several others that suggested to use input_image.eval() or equivalently sess.run() for this conversion, I did the same, but it throws an error and apparently expects a feed_dict value for the sess.run(). But since here I'm not trying to run an operation dependent on unknown values, I don't see the need for the feed_dict here because all I'm doing here is just conversion.

Besides, just so as to check I also tried converting a tf.constant([1,2,3]) value right above it using the same method and it got successfully compiled despite its data type being the same as input_image. Here's my code which is the part of larger script:

```
def call(self, x):
    input_image = Input(shape=(None, None, 3))
    print(input_image.shape)
    print(type(tf.constant([1,2,3])))
    print(type(input_image))
    print(type(K.get_session().run(tf.constant([1,2,3]))))
    print(type(K.get_session().run(input_image)))
```

and here's the error:

```
(?, ?, ?, 3)
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1365, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1350, in _run_fn
    target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1443, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1' with dtype float and shape [?,?,?,3]
     [[{{node input_1}}]]
     [[input_1/_1051]]
  (1) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1' with dtype float and shape [?,?,?,3]
     [[{{node input_1}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

I wonder why the former would work and the latter won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding to (or elaborating on) what @MatiasValdenegro said,

TensorFlow follows something called graph execution (or define-then-run). In other words, when you write a TensorFlow program it defines something called a data-flow graph which shows how the operations you defined are related to each other. And then you execute bits and pieces of that graph depending on the results you're after.

Let's consider two examples. (I am switching to a simple TensorFlow program instead of Keras bits as it makes things more clear - After all `K.get_session()` returns a Session object).

### Example 1

Say you have the following program.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.placeholder(shape=[2,2], dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.float32)
c = a * b

# Wrong: This is what you're doing essentially when you do sess.run(input_image)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(c))

# Right: You need to feed values that c is dependent on
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(c, feed_dict={a: np.array([[1,2],[2,3]])}))
```

Whenever a resulting tensor (e.g. `c`) is dependent on a `placeholder` you cannot execute it and get the result without feeding values to **all** the dependent placeholders.

### Example 2

When you define a `tf.constant(1)` this is not dependent on anything. In other words you don't need a `feed_dict` and can directly run `eval()` or `sess.run()` on it.

### Update: Further explanation on why you need a feed_dict for `input_image`

TLDR: You need a feed_dict because your resulting `Tensor` is produced by an `Input` layer.

Your `input_image` is basically the resulting tensor you get by feeding something to the `Input` layer. Usually in Keras, you are not exposed to the internal placeholder level details. But you would do that via using `model.fit()` or `model.evaluate()`. You can see that Keras `Input` layer in fact uses a placeholder by analysing [this line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/590d6eef7e91a6a7392c8ffffb7b58f2e0c8bc6b/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_layer.py#L121).

Hope I made my point clear that you **do** need to feed in a value to the placeholder to successfully evaluate the output of an `Input` layer. Because that basically holds a placeholder.

### Update 2: How to feed to your `Input` layer

So, appears you can use `feed_dict` with Keras `Input` layer in the following manner. Instead of defining `shape` argument you straight away pass a placeholder to the `tensor` argument, which will bypass the internal placeholder creation in the layer.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import InputLayer
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

x = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, None, None, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
input_image = Input(tensor=x)
arr = np.array([[[[1,1,1]]]])
print(arr.shape)
print(K.get_session().run(input_image, feed_dict={x: arr}))
```

Comment: Please have a look at the code above, I have made some changes to make my points clearer.

Comment: @conjuring Updated my answer. Let me know if you need more clarification on something in the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as "converting" a symbolic tensor to a numpy array, as the latter cannot hold the same kind of information as the former.

When you use `eval()` or `session.run()`, what you are doing is **evaluating** a symbolic expression to get a numerical result, which is a numpy array, but this is not a *conversion*. Evaluating an expression might or might not require additional input data (that's what the `feed_dict` is for), depending on the expression.

Evaluating a constant (`tf.constant`) does not require any input data, but evaluating your other expression does require the input data, so you cannot "convert" this to a numpy array.