# How to convert a Tensor to a numpy array?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to make variational autoencoder, and debugging my code.

I have a Tensor `x_label1`
which is a `Tensor("decoder_4/dense_36/BiasAdd:0", shape=(19185, 74), dtype=float32)`.

But I would like to print this to see all of the values like numpy array.

Is there a way to convert a Tensor into a Numpy array?

Here is my code: https://pastebin.com/7BNbwcxw

I defined `x_label1` as:

```
z_sampled_test = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,), name='z')([z_mean_encoded, z_log_var_encoded])
x_label1 = decoder(z_sampled_test)
```

Comment: Doesn't `tensorflow` have some method or tool to do that?  `numpy` doesn't know about `tensorflow` objects.  At best it can pretend the `tensor` is some sort of nested list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a tensor into a numpy array in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097281/how-can-i-convert-a-tensor-into-a-numpy-array-in-tensorflow)

Comment: You might also find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633370/how-to-print-the-value-of-a-tensor-object-in-tensorflow.

Comment: @AMC I have looked at it, but it did not work. 
When I ```x_label1.eval(session=tf.compat.v1.Session()) ```, it gives me an error, 
```ValueError: Cannot use the given session to evaluate tensor: the tensor's graph is different from the session's graph.```

Comment: @hpaulj I guess so, but I don't know how to make it work..