# How can fix problems in Tensorflow Pix2Pix tutorial?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I am trying to launch TensorFlow Pix2Pix tutorial. I am copy full code from this page: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/pix2pix?hl=NO
I am using tensorflow-gpu 2.3.1
In method

```
def generate_images(model, test_input, tar):
```

in String

```
plt.imshow(display_list[i] * 0.5 + 0.5)
```

I have next error: **NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (add:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported**

```
display_list[i] = Tensor("strided_slice:0", shape=(256, 256, 3), dtype=float32)
```

Maybe somebody tried to launch this tutorial and solved this problem?
Also I am using my dataset, but  when I am tried to launch it with their dataset I got similar problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a tensor to numpy array in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097281/convert-a-tensor-to-numpy-array-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what do you want, but seem the error is like you try to pass Tensor object to numpy. In case you want to do that you can extract value from Tenso object by `Tensor_obj.numpy()`.