# Why does the numpy dot product function returns an error when passed two TensorFlow Variable objects?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = tf.Variable([[12, 13], [12, 13]])
b = tf.Variable([[12, 13], [12, 13]])

print(np.dot(a, b))
```

The above code returns the error:

```
TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.
```

I understand that TensorFlow has a builtin method for matrix multiplication, but I was curious why the `np.dot` method does not work, specifically with tensorflow Variable objects (it seems to do fine with `tensorflow.constant` objects).

Other methods, such as `np.square`, `np.sqrt`, etc. all work with this, but it seems that only `np.dot` in particular does not.

**Edit**: I was wondering *why* these objects in particular do not work when passed to the `np.dot` function. I realize that there are a variety of ways to find the dot product between two `tf.Variable` objects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a tensor to numpy array in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097281/convert-a-tensor-to-numpy-array-in-tensorflow)

Comment: @sehan2 I was more or less wondering *why* this code was returning an error. I realize that you can convert it into an np array, use TF's builtin method, etc. to multiply these.

Comment: Because they aren't numpy arrays. Pretty much every method in numpy library needs a ndarray object to work.

Comment: @AndrewHolmgren In that case, why do methods such as `np.sqrt` work with it? Additionally, the np.dot can also work with tf.constant objects. Is tf.constant just a numpy array? If so, why isn't tf.Variable?

Comment: @aiden I guess with numpy dot method it's happy taking any two iterable arrays with the right shapes and numerical types within (you can put in ndarrays, lists, tuples, etc.). In general, you should explicitly convert to numpy to avoid bugs errors, or alternatively do a@b (which will use the object's preferred multiplication method, in this case tf matmul).

Comment: `numpy` functions, when given non-ndarray arguments, either delegate the action to those arguments (i.e. they need the relevant methods), or try to convert them to arrays.  That's what the `__array__()` method is trying to do (does the traceback say that's a tensorflow method?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in TensorFlow. Please see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/46563. As of July 12, 2021, there is no explanation on that github issue of what causes the problem.

Comment: I see. So if I'm understanding, this error was a result of Tensorflow's changes in the 2.5 version?

Comment: The buggy behavior is not present in version 2.3 but is present in 2.4 and 2.5.