# How to convert from tensor to float

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, tensor, torch

I am having a list of tensors I want to convert to floating points how can I do it. I have tried using `.item` but it is not working. I am getting `ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars`.

```
tensor([[12.1834,  4.9616,  7.7913],
        [ 8.9394,  8.5784,  9.3691],
        [ 9.4475,  8.9766,  9.8418],
        [11.8210,  6.0852,  8.2168],
        [ 8.2885,  6.2607,  9.8877]], grad_fn=<CloneBackward0>)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097281/convert-a-tensor-to-numpy-array-in-tensorflow

Comment: Thanks using `results[1].detach().numpy()` helped me

Answer (score 9):

You just need to cast Tensor constant to numpy object,then can access by index.

```
result.numpy()[0]
```

Comment: Adding `.detach()` before `.numpy()` helped me.