# How to read data in tf.Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

I have dataset for video captioning project. The dataset pipeline for training is Built as:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((videos , tf.ragged.constant(captions)))
```

I want to read all **batch_data** that goes to training step which is look like:

```
class VideoCaptioningModel(keras.Model):
.
.
.
    def train_step(self, batch_data):
        batch_img, batch_seq = batch_data
        batch_loss = 0
        batch_acc = 0
        
        print('batch_data=', batch_data)

.
.
```

The output is:

```
batch_data= (<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 28, 1536) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, None, 8) dtype=int64>)
```

I tried to use `print('batch_data=', batch_data.numpy())`
but I got:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

Comment: Try with `tf.print()` and just use the tensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataset consists of `videos` and `captions` and each entry in your dataset is a `tuple`. See:

```
for x in dataset:
  tf.print(x[0]) # videos
  tf.print(x[1]) # captions
```

Now, note that you can call `.numpy()` on a `tf.Tensor` in `Eager Execution` mode, but tuples do not have this property. So try:

```
tf.print('batch_data=', batch_data[0].numpy())
tf.print('batch_data=', batch_data[1].numpy())
```

Comment: @ AloneTogether,  thanks, but I got this error now:    AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Comment: Yes, because you are in Graph mode and not in Eager Execution mode.. can you show where exactly the error is coming from in your code? I am guessing you are trying to use `tensor.numpy()` inside a `tf.function` and that does not work. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097281/convert-a-tensor-to-numpy-array-in-tensorflow/70782632#70782632