# How to access individual elements within a tensor, excluding the data type?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am using TensorFlow in Google Colaboratory, and I have used a regression model to calculate the coefficients w and b (i.e. slope and intercept). I would like the output to only include the numeric values within the tensor, and exclude the shape and data type.

input:

```
print("Linear Regression Coefficients for Set 1: Slope =", coefficients_set1[0,0], "Intercept =", coefficients_set1[1, 0])
```

output:

Linear Regression Coefficients for Set 1:

```
Slope = tf.Tensor(3.2996964, shape=(), dtype=float32) Intercept = tf.Tensor(99.626526, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

But I would ideally like Coefficients for Set 1:

`Slope = 3.2996964, Intercept = 99.626526`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried casting to numpy (coefficients_set.detach().cpu().numpy())? This way you have the tensor as a numpy array and can access the elements normally. See this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097281/convert-a-tensor-to-numpy-array-in-tensorflow) for tensorflow, the code I shared I use for pytorch, but it should work similarly.

Comment: @Ibrahim That sounds like pytorch code, this question is on tensorflow

Comment: I did mention that in my comment (maybe that's why it sounded like pytorch code to you). I also shared a link to how to do the same in tensorflow, which would be calling "coefficients_set.numpy()" given you're using eager execution (which is the default for tensorflow 2.x).