I need to convert a symbolic Keras tensor into a NumPy array to pass it via PyBind11 to a C++ lib
I use Python 3.12.3, NumPy 1.26.4, TensorFlow 2.17.0 - this one without GPU support.
According to some research, these are compatible. I've installed them in a private environment in my home directory.
I want to implement a custom loss function in Keras, where the actual value will be computed in a C++ library. I know PyBind supports NumPy, so I want to convert one argument of the loss function into NumPy and then pass it to C++.
This is a mockup example to serve as a basis for implementing the PyBind11 transfer mechanism. Some parts make no sense. They are just placeholders for the real implementation.
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras import Model
import numpy
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops

def pinnLoss(yTrue, yPred):
    yArr = numpy.asarray(yPred) # Will be used later.
    squared_difference = math_ops.square(yTrue - yPred)
    return math_ops.mean(squared_difference, axis=-1)  # Note the `axis=-1`

x = numpy.asarray([i for i in range(-50,51)])
y = numpy.asarray([i * i for i in x])
x = x.reshape((len(x), 1))
y = y.reshape((len(y), 1))
scale_x = MinMaxScaler()
x = scale_x.fit_transform(x)
scale_y = MinMaxScaler()
y = scale_y.fit_transform(y)
inputShape = (1,)
inputs = Input(shape=inputShape)
tmp = inputs
tmp = Dense(10, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(tmp)
tmp = Dense(10, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(tmp)
tmp = Dense(1)(tmp)
model = Model(inputs, tmp)
model.compile(loss=pinnLoss, optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x, y, epochs=500, batch_size=10, verbose=0)

The error message comes from the first line of the loss function.
2024-10-14 11:37:04.117027: I external/local_xla/xla/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:32] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2024-10-14 11:37:04.119994: I external/local_xla/xla/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:32] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2024-10-14 11:37:04.129464: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:485] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
2024-10-14 11:37:04.144761: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:8454] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
2024-10-14 11:37:04.149407: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1452] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2024-10-14 11:37:04.975719: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bamer/work/dev/optimizer/src/minimalworking2.py", line 31, in <module>
    model.fit(x, y, epochs=500, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
  File "/home/bamer/ownpython/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/home/bamer/work/dev/optimizer/src/minimalworking2.py", line 11, in pinnLoss
    yArr = numpy.asarray(yPred) # Will be used later.
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic tf.Tensor (data_1:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported.

The situation is the same when I want to convert yTrue in the loss function.
I've read some relevant posts. Some of them deal with performing processing using TensorFlow calls instead of NumPy, and others with incompatible NumPy and TensorFlow versions. Again, others are about switching to eager execution, but TF 2.x already has it as default. Here neither of them seem to be relevant.
EDIT:
I knew the TF 2.x eager execution wrong.  When I enable it using tensorflow.config.run_functions_eagerly(True), the exception does not occur. However, this is not a solution since, in eager mode, this small example takes 145 seconds instead of 11.

You are calling a function on a tensor that is not implemented for tensors. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097281/convert-a-tensor-to-numpy-array-in-tensorflow
Btw I do not understand what you mean in your comment with the eager execution. Your error has nothing to do with it, you are calling the wrong function, or am I missing something?

With eager execution it works. So it is not a symbolic tensor anymore, so it can be converted into the numpy array. The function was right, just doesn't work on symbolic tensors. Anyway, I've switched to PyTorch, where I don't have this problem.
